# Redirect DNS entry to local IIS instance

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-7.5

Can I redirect a DNS entry to a local IIS instance?  I am on a Windows 7 dev box.

I have a domain for hosting static content (images, custom js, css, etc) on a cloud environment.  I'd like to avoid hitting that server during development of the site.

I can see two ways to do this:

1. Create a virtual machine for the site in vmware and map the name to the virtual's ip in etc/hosts.
2. Use a preprocessor macro to prefix image locations with the url for dev/stage/prod.

Is there an easier way to do this?  After searching on SF I found unbound but it looks like its for *nix.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 supports hosts analog to Linux.

Just put the Servername you don't want to be hit in `%WINDIR%\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\HOSTS`

## Edit

This requires the static content to be mirrored on a local instance.

Comment: Yeah, my IIS settings were jacked, I got it to work.